# Date function in PHP gives always date one day behind

Tags: javascript, php, date, php-5.6

My situation is that get always the dates one day behind.
For example, I have this value `-243219600` which is relative to date **18/04/1962**

After a

```
date('d/m/Y', -243219600);
```

Output is :

```
17/04/1962
```

**-243219600** seconds from January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC in **javascript** is 
 [here](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm) you get correct Date.

Comment: I get proper `18/04/1962` as output when I try your code.

Comment: I get the 17th - I'm using UTC. Specifically with `$dt = new DateTime(); $dt->setTimestamp(-243219600); echo $dt->format('r');` I get `Tue, 17 Apr 1962 23:00:00`. So, pretty close to the 18th, but not quite.

Comment: @JitendraPurohit can you tell me what Time zone you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `date()` depends on the configured time zone. If you add the time and timezone, you can see it. In my case it is CET:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:m:i T', -243219600);
//prints: 18/04/1962 00:04:00 CET
```

### Solution with `date()`

If you want `date()` to use `UTC`, use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('d/m/Y H:m:i T', -243219600);"
```

#### Output

```
 17/04/1962 23:04:00 UTC
```

(you see, since it is one hour before midnight in UTC, the date depends on the timezone)

### Solution with `DateTime`:

The `DateTime` class uses always UTC if it is constructed by a Unix timestamp:

From the [documentation](http://en.php.net/datetime.construct):

> #### Note:
>
> The `$timezone` parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the `$time` parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. *@946684800*) or specifies a timezone (e.g. *2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00*).

So you can use the following code as well:

```
echo (new DateTime('@-243219600'))->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: I still get  **17/04/1962** when it should be **18/04/1962**

Comment: No, it shouldn't. In UTC it's **17.04.1962 23:00:00**.

Comment: `new DateTime('@'.strtotime('+1 day', '@-243219600'));` show the correct date

Answer (score 2):

Check the timezone of your PHP, set it so it's the same as your computer (since your using javascript).